# typescript: meta on an interface fields

Tags: typescript

i'm trying to create a framework that would allow me to have meta on interface fields. something like this:

```
function path(path) {}

interface ITwoProps {
  @path('some/path') stringProp: string;
  @path('different/path') boolProp: boolean;
}

class Impl1 implements ITwoProps {
  get stringProp() {
    return 'abc';
  }
  get boolProp() {
    return !!'abc';
  }
}
```

[playground link](http://function%20path(path)%20%7B%7D%20%20interface%20ITwoProps%20%7B%20%20%20@path('some/path')%20stringProp:%20string;%20%20%20@path('different/path')%20boolProp:%20boolean;%20%7D%20%20class%20Impl1%20implements%20ITwoProps%20%7B%20%20%20get%20stringProp()%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20return%20'abc';%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20get%20boolProp()%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20return%20!!'abc';%20%20%20%7D%20%7D)

unfortunately, this does not even compile. error message is a bit obscure, but the idea is that decorators are implicitly disabled on interfaces. it does make sense, since interfaces do not make it into transpiled code, so there won't be transpiled code to attach decorator to.

i also tried another approach, where i would define meta and interface with schema-like objects and extract interfaces from it:

```
const Schema = {
  boolProp: {
    type: Boolean,
    path: 'some/path'
  },
  stringProp: {
    type: String,
    path: 'different/path'
  },
};

type PropertyDef<T> = {
  type: (...args: any[]) => T,
  path?: string;
};

type ExtractType<X> = X extends PropertyDef<infer T> ? T : never;

type ObjectInterface<T extends {[key: string]: PropertyDef}> = {
  [P in keyof T]: ExtractType<T[P]>;
}

class Impl2 implements ObjectInterface<typeof Schema> {
  get foo() {
    return !!'abc';
  }
}
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%20%20%20%20const%20Schema%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20boolProp%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20Boolean%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20path%3A%20'some%2Fpath'%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20stringProp%3A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20String%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20path%3A%20'different%2Fpath'%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%20PropertyDef%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20type%3A%20(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20T%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20path%3F%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%20ExtractType%3CX%3E%20%3D%20X%20extends%20PropertyDef%3Cinfer%20T%3E%20%3F%20T%20%3A%20never%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%20ObjectInterface%3CT%20extends%20%7B%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20PropertyDef%7D%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%5BP%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20ExtractType%3CT%5BP%5D%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20class%20Impl2%20implements%20ObjectInterface%3Ctypeof%20Schema%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20get%20foo()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20!!'abc'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A)

this does not work either, because `PropertyDef` requires a parameter. also this would probably be harder to support for more complex cases than just an interface.

the question is - how does one combine interface with meta in typescript?
while i mostly interested in making 1st approach work, i'm open to different suggestions, maybe even with transformers that use [Compiler API](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API) .

Answer (score 3):

The approach of decorators on interfaces does not have language support, and as
@Daniel-Rosenwasser hints it probably will not have support. An alternative could be to use abstract classes, you can use `implements` with classes to just retain the interface of the class and not the code, although it might be a bit confusing.

I would suggest you look at your second approach again though. It only requires an extra `<any>` to make it work. And it might actually prove more flexibility since you have full control of the metadata system. I played around with creating more complex types using a system similar to this and it can be done. In your case this would work :

```
const Schema = {
  boolProp: {
    type: Boolean,
    path: 'some/path'
  },
  stringProp: {
    type: String,
    path: 'different/path'
  },
};

type PropertyDef<T> = {
  type: (...args: any[]) => T,
  path?: string;
};

type ExtractType<X> = X extends PropertyDef<infer T> ? T : never;

type ObjectInterface<T extends { [key: string]: PropertyDef<any> }> = {
  [P in keyof T]: ExtractType<T[P]>;
}

class Impl2 implements ObjectInterface<typeof Schema> {
  get boolProp() {
    return !!'abc';
  }
  get stringProp() {
    return '';
  }
}
```

Comment: `PropertyDef<any>` seems to work. will play with this approach a little.

Answer (score 0):

Decorators actually have runtime emit, and are given data based on the declarations they are decorating. Interfaces, on the other hand, have no runtime emit, there's nothing to feed to a decorator other than the name.

So really, the issue you're running into is that TypeScript isn't allowing you to place decorators on interface members because it wouldn't make sense in the absence of a build tool.

Comment: that's not an answer. you simply re-phrased the question. it doesn't really help in any way.